# JAVA - eclipse debug remove/change a key in map

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have a situation where I need to **change(remove will also work)** value corresponding to a key in a `Map`.

There are so many  pairs in map. I don't want to copy all and create new map in change value for `Map`.

Is there any way I can directly change/remove value corresponding to a key.

[image]

I have tried changing complete map like :

```
Map m = commandParameters;
m.put("AID","");
return m;
```

But `commandParameters` is not resolved.

I tried changing that particular entry using random expressions, but could not work out.

Is there any way to do so?

**EDIT : ** commandParameters is original map.

Comment: what is `commandParameters`?

Comment: it is the map I need to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a remove on the map for a specific key.

```
commandParameters.remove("AID");
commandParameters.put("AID", "newvalue");
return commandParameters;
```

Comment: remove javadoc says `the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key`, i.e remove does not returns map. So that's not gonna work.

Comment: You need to post more code because what you said doesn't make any sense.  Also the code you posted isn't really complete.  Are you passing the map to a method and then removing?

Comment: yes, correct..my bad. but any idea how to change this value. Not remove.

Comment: may be I can remove and put changed value again :)

Comment: thought same thing. :)